# How to plot multiple graphs (loaded by a loop) into the same 3D plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code loads 15 time-series data via a for loop. The time-series are then transformed into 3D phase space. I would like to plot the 15 trajectories into *one* 3D coordinate system (phase space), but my code creates a new 3D plot for every time-series (`Data`).

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
for Subject in Subjects:
    Data = np.loadtxt("path/to/files...")

    Colormap = plt.get_cmap("tab20c_r")
    Segment_Colormap = Colormap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(Subjects)))

    x_list = pd.Series(Data) # pd.Series
    y_list = x_list.shift(Mean_Lag) # pd.DataFrame.shift
    z_list = x_list.shift(Mean_Lag*2)

    plt.figure().add_subplot(projection="3d")
    plt.plot(x_list, y_list, z_list, lw=0.5,
         c=Segment_Colormap[Subjects.index(Subject)])

plt.show()
```

I know that the issue is due to the fact that the line `plt.figure().add_subplot(projection="3d")` is part of my for loop.

However, when I remove the related code lines out of the loop, such as follows

```
    x_list = pd.Series(Data) # pd.Series
    y_list = x_list.shift(Mean_Lag) # pd.DataFrame.shift
    z_list = x_list.shift(Mean_Lag*2)

plt.figure().add_subplot(projection="3d")
plt.plot(x_list, y_list, z_list, lw=0.5,
         c=Segment_Colormap[Subjects.index(Subject)])

plt.show()
```

the result is that my code only plots the last time-series (`Data`) of the for loop. What would be the solution so that all 15 loaded files by the for loop are plotted into one and the same 3D plot? I didn't face this problem with 2D plots before, so something seems to be different for a 3D plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first case, the issue is that you call `plt.figure().add_subplot(projection="3d")` inside the `for` loop, meaning a new figure is created with each iteration.

In your second case, the issue is that you call `plt.plot(x_list, y_list, z_list, lw=0.5, c=Segment_Colormap[Subjects.index(Subject)])` outside of the `for` loop, meaning only the last iteration is plotted (i.e. the last values of `x_list`, `y_list` and `z_list` are used).

To fix this, you want a combination of the two cases. You want to declare the figure outside of the `for` loop and then call `plot` inside of the `for` loop.

For example (using simple data and two `for` loop iterations):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = z = x
my_list = [x, [2*X for X in x]] # list of lists to be looped over

plt.figure().add_subplot(projection="3d")
for l in my_list:
    plt.plot(l, y, z)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very clear and precise, thank you a lot!